# VHDx on Spanned Volume

Tags: vhdx, dynamic-disk

This is either a great idea, or royally stupid... But I have to try something.

We have a server with 2 x 2TB HDD Dynamic non-os drives in a mirror.
On said mirror, is a dynamic VHDx file for a virual server.

A junior tech simply kept expanding the dynamic VHDx size until the mirror on the host hit 20mb free and brought the VM to a grinding halt with a "Critical-Paused" drive I/O error. Basically, host drive too full.

So now I need to fix the issue and need to check my thinking.

If I break the mirror
Use the second drive as a spanned drive to the first, giving enough space to mount the VHDx/boot VM.
Clean up VHDx
Shrink the VHDx below a single drive size
Decrease the volume on host to below the original single drive
Remove the spanned second drive
Reestablish the mirror

We have backups and all that stuff, but this seems like the quickest way to get the client back online.

Comment: i aint see here a business related (or issue) question in here. I would interpret that you have no space left on your 0.5x2x2TB, which equals 2TB space stoneage hard drives. Upgrade one HDD, let it resync and then the other, or add two parrallel and move the data. That's what the client really needs, not a Raid0 that freaks them out again.